# NextJS: Replace

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js

I have a div in a Next JS application that displays the currency and price of a product once a user enters a product page.

```
<div className="flex">

<Image src={EuroCurrency} alt="Euro Sign} />
<h1 className="ml-5>9.800,00</h1>

</div>
```

Through an onClick event on a button, I want to exchange this div with another, evenly formatted but contextually different, div.

```
<div>

<Image src={DollarCurrency} alt="Dollar Sign} />

<h1 className="ml-5>9,500.00</h1>

</div>
```

This div would need to be hidden until the user clicks the aforementioned button.

I'm aware that this would be achieved through a state - but I'm uncertain on how to hide (and exchange) a complete div.

Answer (score 0):

this is how you can use conditional rendering and useState together to switch the component

```
import React from 'react'
export default function App() {
  const [toggle, setToggle] = React.useState(false);
  
  return (
    <div className="App">
      {toggle ? ( <div >
      <h1 >9.800,00</h1>
      </div>): (<div><h1>9,500.00</h1></div>)
      }
      <button onClick={()=>{setToggle(!toggle)}}>Toogle</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Here you need to change the conditional rendering that suits you like

```
{toggle ? ( COMPONENT 1 ): ( COMPONENT 2 )}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm making a few guesses at what you're asking, but hopefully this example helps.

This is an example of a functional component that uses state to switch between rendering euro and dollars components:

```
import { useState } from 'react';

function MyAwesomeComponent(){ 

// expected state values are "dollar" or "euro"
// if you use TypeScript, you can enforce that,
// but I'm just a TypeScript shill :P

// "dollar" is the initial state
const [currency, setCurrency] = useState("dollar");

return(
  <div className="flex">

     { currency === "dollar" 
       ? <Image src={DollarCurrency} alt="Dollar Sign" />
       : <Image src={EuroCurrency} alt="Euro Sign" />
     }
    
     <h1 className="ml-5">9.800,00</h1>

     <button onClick={
         () => currency === "dollar" ? setCurrency("euro") : setCurrency("dollar")
       }
     > 
       Click to Switch Currency
     </button>

  </div>
)
}
```

There are plenty of other ways to do it. But notice how, instead of having the whole div rendered conditionally and duplicating code, I just render the specific Image component conditionally. Depending on your use case, you could conditionally render divs instead, any component can go in the two slots of the terney expression.